# firewall-cmd blocking snmp

Tags: linux, iptables, firewalld

I inherited a system that has rules implemented with firewall-cmd, it has the below rules. Another system is trying to connect to snmp port (UDP/161) but is not able (my server is responding with ICMP Host administratively prohibited). if I remove the rule "reject-with icmp-host-prohibited" using iptables command from INPUT and FORWARD chains it works fine.

How can I remove this rule using firewall-cmd ? or better, how can I allow the traffic for UDP/161 ?

```
[root@host]# firewall-cmd --direct --get-all-rules
ipv4 filter INPUT_direct 2 -p tcp --dport 10000 -m limit --limit 50/second --limit-burst 1 -j ACCEPT
ipv4 filter INPUT_direct 2 -p tcp --dport 10020 -m limit --limit 50/second --limit-burst 1 -j ACCEPT
ipv4 filter INPUT_direct 2 -p tcp --dport 11000 -m limit --limit 50/second --limit-burst 1 -j ACCEPT
ipv4 filter INPUT_direct 2 -p tcp --dport 11020 -m limit --limit 50/second --limit-burst 1 -j ACCEPT
ipv4 filter INPUT_direct 2 -p udp --dport 161 -j ACCEPT
ipv4 filter OUTPUT 3 -j DROP
ipv4 filter OUTPUT 0 -p icmp -j ACCEPT
ipv4 filter OUTPUT 0 -p tcp -m multiport --dport=53,22,80,443 -j ACCEPT
ipv4 filter OUTPUT 1 -p tcp -m multiport --sport=53,22,80,443 -j ACCEPT
ipv4 filter OUTPUT 0 -p tcp -m multiport --dport=1024:65535 -j ACCEPT
ipv4 filter OUTPUT 1 -p tcp -m multiport --sport=1024:65535 -j ACCEPT
ipv4 filter OUTPUT 0 -p udp -m multiport --dport=1024:65535 -j ACCEPT
ipv4 filter OUTPUT 1 -p udp -m multiport --sport=1024:65535 -j ACCEPT
ipv4 filter OUTPUT 0 -p udp --dport=161 -j ACCEPT
ipv4 filter OUTPUT 1 -p udp --sport=161 -j ACCEPT
ipv4 filter OUTPUT 0 -p udp --dport=162 -j ACCEPT
ipv4 filter OUTPUT 1 -p udp --sport=162 -j ACCEPT
ipv4 filter OUTPUT 0 -p udp --dport=705 -j ACCEPT
ipv4 filter OUTPUT 1 -p udp --sport=705 -j ACCEPT
ipv4 filter INPUT 0 -m pkttype --pkt-type multicast -i ens224 -j ACCEPT
ipv4 filter INPUT 1 -p udp -m udp -i ens224 -j ACCEPT
ipv4 nat PREROUTING 0 -p tcp --destination 172.16.187.39 --dport 10700 -j DNAT --to 172.16.187.7:10700
ipv4 filter FORWARD_direct 2 -p udp --dport 161 -j ACCEPT
```

it is translated to the following iptables rules:

```
[root@host]# iptables -L
Chain INPUT (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination         
ACCEPT     all  --  anywhere             anywhere             ctstate RELATED,ESTABLISHED
ACCEPT     all  --  anywhere             anywhere            
INPUT_direct  all  --  anywhere             anywhere            
INPUT_ZONES_SOURCE  all  --  anywhere             anywhere            
INPUT_ZONES  all  --  anywhere             anywhere            
DROP       all  --  anywhere             anywhere             ctstate INVALID
REJECT     all  --  anywhere             anywhere             reject-with icmp-host-prohibited

Chain FORWARD (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination         
ACCEPT     all  --  anywhere             anywhere             ctstate RELATED,ESTABLISHED
ACCEPT     all  --  anywhere             anywhere            
FORWARD_direct  all  --  anywhere             anywhere            
FORWARD_IN_ZONES_SOURCE  all  --  anywhere             anywhere            
FORWARD_IN_ZONES  all  --  anywhere             anywhere            
FORWARD_OUT_ZONES_SOURCE  all  --  anywhere             anywhere            
FORWARD_OUT_ZONES  all  --  anywhere             anywhere            
DROP       all  --  anywhere             anywhere             ctstate INVALID
REJECT     all  --  anywhere             anywhere             reject-with icmp-host-prohibited

Chain OUTPUT (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination         
OUTPUT_direct  all  --  anywhere             anywhere            

Chain FORWARD_IN_ZONES (1 references)
target     prot opt source               destination         
FWDI_ledefaultzone  all  --  anywhere             anywhere            [goto] 
FWDI_ledefaultzone  all  --  anywhere             anywhere            [goto] 
FWDI_ledefaultzone  all  --  anywhere             anywhere            [goto] 

Chain FORWARD_IN_ZONES_SOURCE (1 references)
target     prot opt source               destination         

Chain FORWARD_OUT_ZONES (1 references)
target     prot opt source               destination         
FWDO_ledefaultzone  all  --  anywhere             anywhere            [goto] 
FWDO_ledefaultzone  all  --  anywhere             anywhere            [goto] 
FWDO_ledefaultzone  all  --  anywhere             anywhere            [goto] 

Chain FORWARD_OUT_ZONES_SOURCE (1 references)
target     prot opt source               destination         

Chain FORWARD_direct (1 references)
target     prot opt source               destination         
ACCEPT     udp  --  anywhere             anywhere             udp dpt:snmp

Chain FWDI_ledefaultzone (3 references)
target     prot opt source               destination         
FWDI_ledefaultzone_log  all  --  anywhere             anywhere            
FWDI_ledefaultzone_deny  all  --  anywhere             anywhere            
FWDI_ledefaultzone_allow  all  --  anywhere             anywhere            
ACCEPT     icmp --  anywhere             anywhere            

Chain FWDI_ledefaultzone_allow (1 references)
target     prot opt source               destination         

Chain FWDI_ledefaultzone_deny (1 references)
target     prot opt source               destination         

Chain FWDI_ledefaultzone_log (1 references)
target     prot opt source               destination         

Chain FWDO_ledefaultzone (3 references)
target     prot opt source               destination         
FWDO_ledefaultzone_log  all  --  anywhere             anywhere            
FWDO_ledefaultzone_deny  all  --  anywhere             anywhere            
FWDO_ledefaultzone_allow  all  --  anywhere             anywhere            

Chain FWDO_ledefaultzone_allow (1 references)
target     prot opt source               destination         

Chain FWDO_ledefaultzone_deny (1 references)
target     prot opt source               destination         

Chain FWDO_ledefaultzone_log (1 references)
target     prot opt source               destination         

Chain INPUT_ZONES (1 references)
target     prot opt source               destination         
IN_ledefaultzone  all  --  anywhere             anywhere            [goto] 
IN_ledefaultzone  all  --  anywhere             anywhere            [goto] 
IN_ledefaultzone  all  --  anywhere             anywhere            [goto] 

Chain INPUT_ZONES_SOURCE (1 references)
target     prot opt source               destination         

Chain INPUT_direct (1 references)
target     prot opt source               destination         
ACCEPT     tcp  --  anywhere             anywhere             tcp dpt:ndmp limit: avg 50/sec burst 1
ACCEPT     tcp  --  anywhere             anywhere             tcp dpt:10020 limit: avg 50/sec burst 1
ACCEPT     tcp  --  anywhere             anywhere             tcp dpt:irisa limit: avg 50/sec burst 1
ACCEPT     tcp  --  anywhere             anywhere             tcp dpt:11020 limit: avg 50/sec burst 1
ACCEPT     udp  --  anywhere             anywhere             udp dpt:snmp
ACCEPT     all  --  anywhere             anywhere             PKTTYPE = multicast
ACCEPT     udp  --  anywhere             anywhere             udp

Chain IN_ledefaultzone (3 references)
target     prot opt source               destination         
IN_ledefaultzone_log  all  --  anywhere             anywhere            
IN_ledefaultzone_deny  all  --  anywhere             anywhere            
IN_ledefaultzone_allow  all  --  anywhere             anywhere            
ACCEPT     icmp --  anywhere             anywhere            

Chain IN_ledefaultzone_allow (1 references)
target     prot opt source               destination         
ACCEPT     tcp  --  anywhere             anywhere             tcp dpt:20701 ctstate NEW
ACCEPT     tcp  --  anywhere             anywhere             tcp dpt:33000 ctstate NEW
ACCEPT     tcp  --  anywhere             anywhere             tcp dpt:7199 ctstate NEW
ACCEPT     tcp  --  anywhere             anywhere             tcp dpt:yo-main ctstate NEW
ACCEPT     tcp  --  anywhere             anywhere             tcp dpt:33003 ctstate NEW
ACCEPT     tcp  --  anywhere             anywhere             tcp dpt:10742 ctstate NEW
ACCEPT     tcp  --  anywhere             anywhere             tcp dpt:33005 ctstate NEW
ACCEPT     tcp  --  anywhere             anywhere             tcp dpt:rmiregistry ctstate NEW
ACCEPT     tcp  --  anywhere             anywhere             tcp dpt:10701 ctstate NEW
ACCEPT     tcp  --  anywhere             anywhere             tcp dpt:33002 ctstate NEW
ACCEPT     tcp  --  anywhere             anywhere             tcp dpt:11443 ctstate NEW
ACCEPT     tcp  --  anywhere             anywhere             tcp dpt:ssh ctstate NEW
ACCEPT     tcp  --  anywhere             anywhere             tcp dpt:20601 ctstate NEW
ACCEPT     tcp  --  anywhere             anywhere             tcp dpt:33004 ctstate NEW
ACCEPT     udp  --  anywhere             anywhere             udp dpt:ntp ctstate NEW
ACCEPT     tcp  --  anywhere             anywhere             tcp dpt:10700 ctstate NEW
ACCEPT     tcp  --  anywhere             anywhere             tcp dpt:33006 ctstate NEW
ACCEPT     tcp  --  anywhere             anywhere             tcp dpt:10760 ctstate NEW
ACCEPT     tcp  --  anywhere             anywhere             tcp dpt:blocks ctstate NEW
ACCEPT     tcp  --  anywhere             anywhere             tcp dpt:20700 ctstate NEW
ACCEPT     tcp  --  anywhere             anywhere             tcp dpt:33001 ctstate NEW
ACCEPT     tcp  --  anywhere             anywhere             tcp dpt:amanda ctstate NEW
ACCEPT     tcp  --  anywhere             anywhere             tcp dpt:23232 ctstate NEW
ACCEPT     tcp  --  anywhere             anywhere             tcp dpt:10388 ctstate NEW
ACCEPT     tcp  --  anywhere             anywhere             tcp dpt:20600 ctstate NEW
ACCEPT     tcp  --  anywhere             anywhere             tcp dpt:10181 ctstate NEW

Chain IN_ledefaultzone_deny (1 references)
target     prot opt source               destination         

Chain IN_ledefaultzone_log (1 references)
target     prot opt source               destination         

Chain OUTPUT_direct (1 references)
target     prot opt source               destination         
ACCEPT     icmp --  anywhere             anywhere            
ACCEPT     tcp  --  anywhere             anywhere             multiport dports domain,ssh,http,https
ACCEPT     tcp  --  anywhere             anywhere             multiport dports 1024:65535
ACCEPT     udp  --  anywhere             anywhere             multiport dports 1024:65535
ACCEPT     udp  --  anywhere             anywhere             udp dpt:snmp
ACCEPT     udp  --  anywhere             anywhere             udp dpt:snmptrap
ACCEPT     udp  --  anywhere             anywhere             udp dpt:agentx
ACCEPT     tcp  --  anywhere             anywhere             multiport sports domain,ssh,http,https
ACCEPT     tcp  --  anywhere             anywhere             multiport sports 1024:65535
ACCEPT     udp  --  anywhere             anywhere             multiport sports 1024:65535
ACCEPT     udp  --  anywhere             anywhere             udp spt:snmp
ACCEPT     udp  --  anywhere             anywhere             udp spt:snmptrap
ACCEPT     udp  --  anywhere             anywhere             udp spt:agentx
DROP       all  --  anywhere             anywhere
```

Comment: Try this.... `firewall-cmd --permanent --zone=public --add-port=161/udp`, then `firewall-cmd --reload`, and then `firewall-cmd --list-ports`.... You should also be able to use `netstat -ano` to confirm the port is listening perhaps.

Comment: thanks the command solved the my problem, just had to replace zone 'public' with the active zone. please put your comment as an answer and I'll accept it

Comment: As requested, I've added as an answer with more thorough detail though as I normally do. I'm glad to help you get this fixed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the [firewall-cmd](https://firewalld.org/documentation/man-pages/firewall-cmd.html) CLI client tool to add a permanent rule and allow the specific UDP port through the **firewalld daemon** for the applicable zone.

> ### 1. Get the Active Interface Zone(s)
>
> ```
> --get-active-zones
> ```
>
> ---
>
> ### 2. Allowing the UDP Port Traffic Through
>
> ```
> firewall-cmd --permanent --zone=<zone> --add-port=161/udp
> firewall-cmd --reload
> ```
>
> > **Note:** The `<zone>` value will be the value needed per the command #1.
>
> ---
>
> ### 3. Confirming
>
> ```
> firewall-cmd --list-ports
> ```

---

### Further Resources

- [firewall-cmd](https://firewalld.org/documentation/man-pages/firewall-cmd.html)

  > ```
  > --get-active-zones
  > ```
  >
  > Print currently active zones altogether with interfaces and sources used in these zones. Active zones are zones, that have a
  >   binding to an interface or source. The output format is:
  >
  > ---
  >
  > ```
  > --permanent
  > ```
  >
  > The permanent option --permanent can be used to set options
  >   permanently. These changes are not effective immediately, only after
  >   service restart/reload or system reboot. Without the --permanent
  >   option, a change will only be part of the runtime configuration.
  >
  > If you want to make a change in runtime and permanent configuration,
  >   use the same call with and without the --permanent option.
  >
  > The --permanent option can be optionally added to all options further
  >   down where it is supported.
  >
  > ---
  >
  > ```
  > [--permanent] [--zone=zone] --add-port=portid[-portid]/protocol [--timeout=timeval]
  > ```
  >
  > Add the port for zone. If zone is omitted, default zone will be used.
  >   This option can be specified multiple times. If a timeout is supplied,
  >   the rule will be active for the specified amount of time and will be
  >   removed automatically afterwards. timeval is either a number (of
  >   seconds) or number followed by one of characters s (seconds), m
  >   (minutes), h (hours), for example 20m or 1h.
  >
  > The port can either be a single port number or a port range
  >   portid-portid. The protocol can either be tcp, udp, sctp or dccp.
  >
  > ---